# Evaluate the electrical resistance between any two points of a circuit

Tags: graphs-and-networks, physics

I have an electric circuit of which the structure is known but the value of the single components (all resistors) is not. I can measure experimentally the resistance between some points of my circuit. Is there a way to obtain, in a faster way than doing it by hand, analytical expression for the measured resistances in terms of the circuit resistors, so that I can try to solve a system to obtain them?

In the circuit I'm analyzing there are 7 resistors and I can measure 10+ resistances, some of which are redundant.

Comment: Perhaps, this question should be asked on the EE or physics stackexchange site.  It does not seem to involve Mathematica software.

Comment: It is not really a physics question, I know how to do it with paper and pen. I was wondering if Mathematica can speed up the process!

Comment: If you can write all the equations governing the circuit, and provide values of enough of the electrical quantities, Mathematica can solve for the rest by matrix inversion.

Comment: I second bbgodfrey's suggestion. Unless there is something tricky going on, it seems to me that the core (if not the entirety) of the question is to solve a system of equations.